# Input command taking input as an int instead of a str in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner programing with Python 2.79.  I am writing a program that "tokenizes" a mathematical formula, basically turning each number and operator into an item in a list.

My problem is currently (because it is a semantic error i haven't been able to test the rest of the code yet) in my input command.  I am asking the user to enter a mathematical equation.  Python is interpreting this as an int.

I tried making it into a string, and Python basically solved the formula, and ran the solution through my tokenize function

My code is as follows:

```
#Turn a math formula into tokens

def token(s):
    #Strip out the white space
    s.replace(' ', '')
    token_list = []
    i = 0
    #Create tokens
    while i < len(s):
        #tokenize the operators
        if s[i] in '*/\^':
            token_list.append(s[i])
        #Determine if operator of negation, and tokenize
        elif s[i] in '+-':
            if i > 0 and s[i - 1].isdigit() or s[i - 1] == ')':
                token_list.append(s[i])
            else:
                num = s[i]
                i += 1
                while i < len(s) and s[i].isdigit():
                    num += s[i]
                    i += 1
                token_list.append(num)
        elif s[i].isdigit():
            num = ''
            while i < len(s) and s[i].isdigit():
                num += s[i]
                i += 1
            token_list.append(num)
        else:
            return []
    return token_list

def main():
    s = str(input('Enter a math equation: '))
    result = token(s)
    print(result)

main()
```

Any help would be appreciated

I am looking to

Comment: use `raw_input` instead of input. input sucks.

Comment: In Python 2.x you have to use `raw_input`, not `input`.

Comment: Also, `str.replace()` doesn't work in-place. Do `s = s.replace(...)` to get what you want.

Comment: Thank You!  I am learning on Python 3.4, but am using 2.79 today because of the Linux machine i am on.  I guess they are different in that way.

Comment: Thanks for the S.replace info.

Comment: @DntMesArnd FYI the reason input "sucks" on Py2 (since no one said) is because it is equivalent to `eval(input(...))` on Py3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Python is interpreting the user's input as an integer is because of the line `input('Enter a math equation: ')`. Python interprets that as `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. The `raw_input` function creates a string from the user input, and `eval` evaluates that input -- so an input of `5+2` is considered `"5+2"` by `raw_input`, and `eval` evaluates that to be `7`.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)